# can laravel 7 and 9 live on php 8.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-9, php-7.4, php-8.1

I have some applications using laravel 7 with PHP7.4 and now I want to make an application with laravel 9 and it looks like I have to upgrade PHP to version 8.1 (cmiiw), and the problem is that Laravel 7 can't run smoothly (many depricated) on PHP 8.1.

Is there a way to get laravel 7 and 9 to run together on php 8.1 without having to upgrade my application which is laravel 7 to 9 ?

Comment: Firstly, whether you "have to" update to PHP 8.1 is something we can't answer; it's up to whatever policy you want to follow. Secondly, a *deprecation* doesn't (or shouldn't) stop anything running - it is advance warning about a *future* change. Looking at [a table on the Laravel site](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#support-policy), Laravel 7 officially supported PHP 8.0, and the number of compatibility breaks in PHP 8.1 should be very low. I think you need to be more specific about what you mean by "can't run smoothly".

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 9 requires php: `^8.0.2`  from [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel#9.x-dev).

Laravel 7 requires php: `^7.2.5|^8.0` from [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel#7.x-dev).
(keep in mind EOL in 2021, recommended upgrade).

So you can use `>=^8.0.2`, see more about the [^](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-).